# Problems with the IFCJS floorplan system

Tags: ifc

i need some help, i have this error using a floorplans, but I believe this error comes from something I did wrong in the visibility part, can help me?

[the image before selecting the plan appears on the background as edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvRqm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I'll leave my solution here in case you need to help someone.
You need to activate the `togglePostproduction` function. like so:

```
togglePostproduction();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using [web-ifc-viewer](https://github.com/ifcjs/web-ifc-viewer). Just to give some more insight on this, the postproduction of `web-ifc-viewer` is an additional HTML elements that is displayed on top of the Three.js canvas.

For performance reasons, this layer only gets updated when the user stops moving the camera. When you go into floorplan mode, you need to disable the postproduction manually. This can be done like this:

```
ifcViewer.context.postProduction.active = false;
```

This also means that when you go back to 3D mode, you probably need to activate it again. FYI, you can also update the postproduction on demand:

```
ifcViewer.context.postProduction.update();
```